# How to sum of array object in Javascipt

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this array:

```
    var res =
[
  { '5': 0 },  { '23': 0 },
  { '74': 0 }, { '45': 0 },
  { '10': 0 }, { '46': 1 },
  { '33': 0 }, { '18': 0 },
  { '67': 1 }, { '28': 0 },
  { '68': 0 }, { '56': 0 },
  { '78': 0 }, { '71': 0 },
  { '50': 1 }, { '14': 0 },
  { '39': 0 }, { '91': 0 },
  { '37': 0 }, { '34': 0 }
];
```

I want to sum second values to get result. like in this example result must be 2.
I am using nodejs, if it helps.

Thank you.

Comment: I would probably first go back to the code that generated this data and put it in a more convenient way to process.  An object with unknown keys is usually a sign that there's a better way to store and therefore process this data.

Comment: And, what should your sum do if an object has more than one property in it?

Comment: As a hint `Object.values(obj)[0]` will get you the "first" value in an object where "first" is in quotes because if there's more than one value, it's not clear what your algorithm wants to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Object.values` to extract the value for each such object and then sum them. Using `map` and `reduce`, this can even be done in a one liner:

```js
const total =  res.map(o => Object.values(o)[0]).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

Comment: @Corvus actually, the conversion to number is redundant - I didn't notice you already had number literals there. I've edited my answer to remove it.